# Rails 4: Unable to create checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm having a hard time implementing a checkout process where once at the cart, user can checkout and have order shipped. Maybe I need an order model and transaction controller?

I'm just not sure how to set those up. Currently the cart works and can be cleared as well as have items be added, its just I'm not sure how to implement a checkout and order system.

Idea is: User at cart clicks the checkout button, then is taken to checkout where he/she can input payment information, then taken back to products page. Issue is I'm not sure again how to connect the cart to the checkout and payment process into one simple easy system.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm still very new at this. Thank you.

```
class CartController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

    def add
        id = params[:id]
            if session[:cart] then
               cart = session[:cart]
            else
                session[:cart] = {}
                cart = session[:cart]
            end
            if cart[id] then
               cart[id] = cart[id] + 1
            else
               cart[id] = 1
            end
                redirect_to :action => :index
                flash[:notice] = 'added to cart' 
     end


    def clearCart  
        session[:cart] = nil
        redirect_to :action => :index
        flash[:notice] = 'cart cleared' 
    end


    def index
        if session[:cart] then
            @cart = session[:cart]
        else
            @cart = {}
        end
    end     
end
```

---

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_product, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @product = Product.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.save
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end


  private
    def set_product
      @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    end

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:title, :description, :price, :category, :subcategory)
    end

end
```

---

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

---

views/cart/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Your Cart</h1>


<% if @cart.empty? %>

<p> Your cart is currently empty</p>

<% else %>

<%= link_to 'Empty your Cart', cart_clear_path %>
<br><br>
<% end %>

<% total = 0 %>

<ul>
<% @cart.each do | id, quantity |  %>  
    <% product = Product.find_by_id(id) %>

    <li>
        <%= link_to product.title, product %>
        <p><%= product.description %></p>
        <p><%= number_to_currency product.price %></p>
        <p>Quantity: <%= quantity  %></p>
    </li>

    <% total += quantity * product.price %>

<% end %>

    <p><b><%= number_to_currency total, :unit => '$' %> </b></p>    

</ul>
```

---

---

**What I've tried below**

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :cart
end
```

cart.rb

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items
    has_one :order
end
```

Orders_Controller.rb

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /orders
  # GET /orders.json
  def index
    @orders = Order.all
  end

  # GET /orders/1
  # GET /orders/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1
  # PATCH/PUT /orders/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /orders/1
  # DELETE /orders/1.json
  def destroy
    @order.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to orders_url, notice: 'Order was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_order
      @order = Order.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:new, :cart_id, :ip_address, :first_name, :last_name, :user_id)
    end
end
```

added Checkout to views/cart/index.html.erb

```
<%= link_to "Checkout", new_order_path, class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

What do I do after this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've used a local variable product, not the controller attribute `@product`. (just add the `'@'` sign)

my advise to you is to use a gem like [shoppe](https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe),
you can see example [here](https://github.com/tryshoppe/shoppe-example) ([demo](http://demo.tryshoppe.com/))

you can also navigate through the models of the gem to see how they did it, maybe it will give you a clear perspective of writing an e-commerce solution.